# How to develop react native on remote PC on same network?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-emulator

I have a headless ubuntu server at home along with my Windows PC. I use it to serve my development stuff. I want to work on my first react native project.

But whether or not I use expo or native-cli I can't run the emulator on my Windows PC while the native app is created and held on my headless ubuntu server. I run my IDE and emulators on my windows PC but I host the app on my headless server on the same home network.

But it seems everything needs to be on the same machine for me to run emulators with the app. Is there anyway around this? PS. I only have one Android device and I want to be able to test on multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its okay. instead of using `LAN` in expo just use a `Tunnel` instead and then start all the required emulators on your windowsPC.

Download the expo application on emulators and sign in and you can test using the project under development.

Comment: what if using react native cli, and not expo. is there a way?